# MaterialDrawer add profile option

Tags: java, android, materialdrawer

I'm using the [MaterialDrawer](https://mikepenz.github.io/MaterialDrawer/) library by Mike Penz.

I made an AccountHeader and now wondered how to add such an "**add Account**" button (see the picture). Is there allready a provided method how to do this?
Like by pressing this button sth appears to let you insert information of a new account?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AccountHeaderBuilder.build()` function returns a `AccountHeader` object. You should keep the reference to this one, as it will allow you to update contents of the `AccountHeader` at a later time.

So you'll create your `AccountHeader` like this

```
AccountHeader headerResult = new AccountHeaderBuilder()
    .withActivity(this)
    .addProfiles(...)
    .build();
```

After that you have the `headerResult` if you take a look in the [javadoc](http://javadoc.io/doc/com.mikepenz/materialdrawer/5.9.3) you will see that there are 2 methods which will be useful for you.

There is `addProfiles` and `addProfile` which allows you to add a new profile to the drawer. Equally there is `removeProfile`, and `updateProfile` (which you will use when one profile was modified)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't konw about this website :)

Answer (score 0):

How you are doing for the other two...same thing you have to do for that.

Comment: I guess I'll edit my question to be more specific. I don't want just an item for my drawer, but a method which let's you add a new account on button press.

Comment: Then you have to create a list view or recycler view inside your navigation view and handle it.